# CMake, "IMPORTED" libraries and Find scripts

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, mpi

I am trying to include MPI in a project and add it as an imported library in my CMake project. This is my code:

```
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
add_library(MPI SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET MPI PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
set_property(TARGET MPI PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES})
```

This gives me the following error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.10.2_1/lib/libmpi_cxx.dylib;/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.10.2_1/lib/libmpi.dylib'
```

I believe this is because the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` is just a single file and not what `FindMPI.cmake` returns. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus: As I understand, `find_package()` works for the author, but he wants to organize results of this call as IMPORTED library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first element in the list as *IMPORTED_LOCATION* property, use other elements as *INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES* property:

```
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
add_library(MPI SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET MPI PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
# Copy list for prevent its from modification.
set(other_elems ${MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES})
list(GET other_elems 0 first_elem)
list(REMOVE_AT other_elems 0)
set_property(TARGET MPI PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${first_elem})
set_property(TARGET MPI PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ${other_elems})
```

Comment: it seems that most of these old `Find` scripts will not fit in well with the new library based direction that cmake is heading in... any ideas how these could coexist?

Comment: `old Find scripts will not fit in well with the new library based direction` - or "new library based directions" doesn't perfectly fit for all packages. My approach for multi-library package doesn't look as intuitive decision, but a hack. It is unclear (at least, for me), whether all Find script's developers *must* follow that approach.